# AWS Cloud formation delete resource before creating

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I tried to write cloud formation script for creating dynamodb. When i execute script its getting error **already exists in stack**.

This is my template.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Resources: 
  terminationLettersDynamodb:
      Type: 'AWS::DynamoDB::Table'
      DeletionPolicy: Delete
      Properties:
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: schemeId
            AttributeType: S

        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: schemeId
            KeyType: HASH

        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 1
          WriteCapacityUnits: 1
        TableName: "terminationLetters"
```

Is there any way to delete resource before creating.?

Comment: The error indicates that you have one or more custom-named resources with the same name. An example would be: you have 2 DynamoDB tables with the same name: terminationLetters. Check your resource names. Here's an article from AWS explaining this exact error: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudformation-stack-resource-failure/.

Comment: I need to drop existing table and recreate.

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid using hardcoded table names. If you specify a name, you cannot perform updates that require replacement of this resource.

When leaving out the TableName, you can reference the dynamically created table name elsewhere in your stack with the `Ref` intrinsic function, e.g.: Ref "terminationLettersDynamodb"